# How to run rs.init from mongo statefulset yaml file?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I am deploying a mongodb statefulset on kubernetes cluster (GKE).

Every time when I **first** deploy the statefulset I have to run the following command **manually** on mongo statefulset.

My steps:

1. deploy the yaml file
2. enter to mongo pod by "**kubectl exec -it mongo-0 /bin/bash**"
3. run "**mongo**"
4. run

   rs.initiate( {
   _id : "rs0",
   members: [
   { _id: 0, host: "mongo-0.mongo:27017" },
   { _id: 1, host: "mongo-1.mongo:27017" }
   ]
   })

to initiate

Can I put this command in mongo-statefulset.yml file or another ways to handle it **automatically**?

mongo-statefulset.yml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  selector:
     matchLabels:
       role: mongo
  serviceName: "mongo"
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: mongo
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: mongo
          image: mongo:4.0
          command:
            - mongod
            - "--replSet"
            - rs0
            - "--bind_ip"
            - 0.0.0.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
```

Also another critical problem:

Sometime I don't know why all of my pods inside my cluster would **suddenly be restarted**, everything is normal from being restarted and keep running **except** this mongo stateful set. The replica set status of mongo became "**OTHER**" instead of "Primary/Secondary". Therefore, the mongo service cannot be used until I type the following command to recover it:

```
rsconf = rs.conf()
rsconf.members = [
      { _id: 0, host: "mongo-0.mongo:27017", priority: 1 },
      { _id: 1, host: "mongo-1.mongo:27017", priority: 0.5 }
   ]
rs.reconfig(rsconf, {force: true})
```

How to recover it automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Two options here:

- Use Kubernetes [Lifecyle Hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/). The `PostStart` hook would lend itself to your usecase. However, make sure to build in a check that validates whether your mongo has started, before running the configuration call. The hook is also executed when K8s decides to restart a Pod.
- Use [Helm Chart Hooks](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/). This adds the option to differentiate between post-install and post-upgrade. However, these hooks will only be fired after Helm installation of upgrading of the chart and not when K8s restarts the Pod.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [sidecar container](https://github.com/cvallance/mongo-k8s-sidecar) which will do this for ya